# Extract string in PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql, string

I got the following column:

```
full_path "gorfs"."absolute_pathname"
```

It keeps the path of a BLOB, like on the example below:

[image]

Note that the **`4865`** is the `account_id`.The path is always like: `/userfiles/account/ACCOUNTID`

I need to extract that, to use in another query. For example:

```
select * from gorfs.seg WHERE account_id = 4865
```

How can I extract that value from the `full_path` column?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Just this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8612456/939860

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the account id is **always** at the third position use `split_part()`

```
select * 
from gorfs.seg 
WHERE split_part(full_path, '/', 4) = '4865'
```

Note that due to the leading `/` the actual index is 4, not 3.

The following query:

```
with seg (id, full_path) as (
  values 
      (1, '/userfiles/account/4556/attachment/1234'), 
      (2, '/userfiles/account/123/attachment/1234'), 
      (3, '/userfiles/account/7890/attachment/1234'),
      (4, '/userfiles/account/4556/attachment/56789')
)
select *
from seg
where split_part(full_path, '/', 4) = '4556'
```

returns

```
id | full_path                               
---+-----------------------------------------
 1 | /userfiles/account/4556/attachment/1234 
 4 | /userfiles/account/4556/attachment/56789
```

If you want to put that into a view, you can use:

```
create or replace view v_seg
as
select st_ino, 
       segment_index, 
       st_ino_target, 
       full_path, 
       split_part(full_path, '/', 4) as account_id
from gorfs.seg;
```

Answer (score 3):

This turned out to be a tricky puzzle which took up far more time than I thought it would - I guess for you too? :-).

I (finally) managed to solve it thus: First I created (using DDL and DML for those who wish to try this at home) a table called stringtest:

```
CREATE TABLE stringtest (my_string VARCHAR(255));
```

and populated it as below

```
INSERT INTO stringtest VALUES('/blah/moreblah/4556/stuff/file.name');
INSERT INTO stringtest VALUES('/blah/moreblah/stuff/3434/file.name');
INSERT INTO stringtest VALUES('/users/test/34343/sfdsfs/6778');
INSERT INTO stringtest VALUES('/users/test/34343/sfdsfs/677990');
```

Then I used regexp_matches as I thought would be natural

```
ntest=# SELECT (regexp_matches(my_string, '\d+')) FROM stringtest;
 regexp_matches 
----------------
 {4556}
 {3434}
 {34343}
 {34343}
(4 rows)
```

So, I thought, this is easy-peasy - over in two seconds. How wrong was I!!

I then tried all sorts of typecasts (chained as well as single!), functions and assorted Googling to no avail.

The **key** to this problem is to realise that regexp_matches returns an **array** (hence the little curly braces around the fields) of strings. So, PostgreSQL (unsurpsingly perhaps) can't convert an array of strings into an integer. More frantic Googling ensued and I came across [this gem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13287756/470530).

The key is the array_to_string function. The answer I came up with is this:

```
ntest=# SELECT ((array_to_string(regexp_matches(my_string, '\d+', 'i'), ';'))::integer) + 5 
AS IntTest FROM stringtest;

 inttest 
---------
    4561
    3439
   34348
   34348
(4 rows)
```

The `+5` isn't strictly necessary (note the change in values) - it was just a test to prove that they are indeed treated as `INTEGER`s. Obviously, since they're `account_ids`, you won't be performing arithmetic on them.

[EDIT]

Following the OP's comment below about adding a `WHERE` clause, I tried the following. A simple `WHERE` (...array_to_string = value...) doesn't appear to work.

Next, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165450/store-common-query-as-column/11166268#11166268), I tried

```
ntest=# CREATE FUNCTION colint(stringtest)
ntest-#   RETURNS integer AS
ntest-# $func$
ntest$#     SELECT (array_to_string(regexp_matches(my_string, '\d+', 'i'), ';'))::integer
ntest$#     FROM   stringtest
ntest$# $func$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

but, that doesn't work - appears to be a bug in PostgreSQL AFICS.

```
ntest=# select *, stringtest.colint from stringtest; 
              my_string              | colint 
-------------------------------------+--------
 /blah/moreblah/4556/stuff/file.name |   4556
 /blah/moreblah/stuff/3434/file.name |   4556
 /users/test/34343/sfdsfs/6778       |   4556
 /users/test/34343/sfdsfs/677990     |   4556
(4 rows)
```

**Definitely** bad - same value for all of my function's derived values.

So, next I tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32188613/470530) using a `CTE` and bingo!

```
WITH tab AS
(
  SELECT *, (array_to_string(regexp_matches(my_string, '\d+', 'i'), ';'))::integer AS t
  FROM stringtest
)
SELECT * FROM tab
WHERE tab.t = 3434;
```

Result:

```
    my_string              |  t   
-------------------------------------+------
 /blah/moreblah/stuff/3434/file.name | 3434
(1 row)
```

Seems like a bit of a hack, but it gets the job done! :-) If you only want 
specific columns in stringtest, name the columns individually in tab - e.g.

```
ntest=# WITH tab AS
ntest-# (
ntest(#   SELECT my_string, (array_to_string(regexp_matches(my_string, '\d+', 'i'), ';'))::integer AS t
ntest(#   FROM stringtest
ntest(# )
ntest-# SELECT my_string FROM tab
ntest-# WHERE tab.t = 3434;
              my_string              
-------------------------------------
 /blah/moreblah/stuff/3434/file.name
(1 row)
```

Final thought, it might be just as well to have a `TRIGGER` on the table and do an `INSERT` into an additional field of just the `account_id` integer - that would make it very efficient for searching - it's a pity that PostgreSQL's [persisted | calculated | computed | generated] field functionality isn't up to the job - they are pretty cool when used correctly.

[FINAL EDIT]

I was thinking that this shouldn't be that tricky - and then I pondered [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) - don't make things more complicated than they have to be - or [K.I.S.S.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Would you believe that this works a treat?

```
CREATE VIEW vtest AS 
SELECT *, (SELECT ((array_to_string(regexp_matches(my_string, '\d+', 'i'), ';'))::integer) 
AS account_id)
FROM stringtest;
```

Now the view:

```
ntest=# select * from vtest;
              my_string              | account_id 
-------------------------------------+------------
 /blah/moreblah/4556/stuff/file.name |       4556
 /blah/moreblah/stuff/3434/file.name |       3434
 /users/test/34343/sfdsfs/6778       |      34343
 /users/test/34343/sfdsfs/677990     |      34343
(4 rows)
```

And, selecting from same with `WHERE` clause:

```
ntest=# select * from vtest where account_id = 4556;
```

gives (gulp... after all that! :-) )

```
              my_string              | account_id 
-------------------------------------+------------
 /blah/moreblah/4556/stuff/file.name |       4556
(1 row)
```

Comment: That's great!! Just one more thing: Can I add some **WHERE** clause to it? Like: `WHERE id = 4561` ?

Comment: @JohnThomaz - check out my edit and final thought - HTH.

Comment: You are right it does not need to be _that_ complicated (or tricky). A simple `split_part()` will do.

Comment: `but, that doesn't work - appears to be a bug in PostgreSQL AFICS.` *What* does not work exactly? The function looks fine. (Except that all of this seems like overkill in the face of a simple `split_part()`)

Answer (score 1):

...or you can simply use parenthesis to isolate the components and cast as usual:

```
select ((regexp_matches(full_path, '\d+'))[1])::int
from gorfs.seg
where account_id = 4865
```

The question is: why do you need to extract the `account_id` from the `full_path` if you already have it in the `where` clause?